# 404 not found error after deploying Laravel 8 application on shared hosting

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting

I'm deploying my Laravel 8 and MySQL application on Hostinger shared hosting and after finishing all the steps, I'm getting 404 not found error instead of my website content.

So this is my files directory structure:

[image]

This my index.php file located in my public folder:

[image]

and .htaccess file located in my public folder:

[image]

Could you please check and locate where the error is?

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create an folder under the root path (for instance: app),
Step2: Move all project content under app folder

e.g:

```
/
  /app
  /public_html
```

Step3: copy public folder's content to public_html
Step4: change the index.php paths with new structure

e.g: "../app/vendors" etc. (same for other paths)

Step5: Update .env credentials

it should works

Comment: unfortunately this solution didn't resolve my problem

Comment: @AhmedMissaoui can you contact me on linkedin or my e-mail address ? (omeratayilmaz@gmail.com) we can make a google meet or anydesk connection for solving this problem easily

Comment: i just emailed you